# Login to website using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am writing a spider. In which I am trying to scraping a website using scraping by logging into that website. I have write a spider but still getting problem in logging into the website. I had write the whole spider but can't resolve the issue of getting logging in. Please have a look at my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class ScotlandSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scotland'
    allowed_domains = ['www.whoownsscotland.org.uk']
    login_url = r'http://www.whoownsscotland.org.uk/login.php?p=%2Fsearch.php'
    start_urls = ['http://www.whoownsscotland.org.uk/search.php']

    def login(self , response):
        data = {
            'name' : 'USERNAME',
            'pass' : 'PASSWORD',
            'previous' : r'%2Fsearch.php',
            'login' : 'login'
        }
        yield FormRequest(url=self.login_url, formdata=data ,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        links = response.xpath('//p/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absoulute_url = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_url , callback=self.parse_links)

    def parse_links(self , response):
        cities = response.xpath('//*[@id="layout-right"]/table/tr/td/p/a/@href').extract()
        for city in cities:
            absoulute_url_new = response.urljoin(city)
            yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_url_new , callback=self.parse_cities)

    def parse_cities(self , response):
        record = response.xpath('//*[@id="layout-left"]/table/tr')
        estate =  record[0].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        courty =  record[1].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        grid_ref =  record[2].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        acreage =  record[3].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        os_15 =  record[4].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        owner  = record[5].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        owner_address = record[6].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        property_address = record[7].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        website  = record[8].xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        further_info = record[9].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        contacts = record[10].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        regsiters_sheet = record[11].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        regsiters_certificate = record[12].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
        currency_of_data = record[13].xpath('.//td//text()').extract()

        yield {
            "Estate" : estate,
            "County" : courty,
            "Grid Reference" : grid_ref,
            "Acreage" : acreage,
            "OS 1:50k Sheet" : os_15,
            "Owner" : owner,
            "Owner Address" : owner_address,
            "Property Address" : property_address,
            "Website" : website,
            "Further Information" : further_info,
            "Contacts" : contacts,
            "Registers of Scotland Sasines Search Sheet No" : regsiters_sheet,
            "Registers of Scotland Land Certificate No" : regsiters_certificate ,
            "Currency of Data" : currency_of_data
        }
```

Comment: You should change the password in your account since you just posted it and it will be visible in edits from now on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: you've created the `login()` method, but you never call it.

The simplest way to solve this is to rename that method to [`start_requests()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests).
This method will then be called by scrapy to generate the initial requests, instead of generating them from `start_urls`.

Comment: still facing problem, I am new to scrapy could you please make the changes that are required to my code that I could run it.

Comment: @haider Read [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project) and effect the necessary changes to your code yourself.

Comment: @haider The method name is the only thing you need to change to get the login to work. I tested this before you changed the password. If there are other problems, maybe a new question is in order.