# Scraping website that requires authentication using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** this website:
https://www.albertacannabis.org/

In order to access to its products, I have to authenticate a session. Thing is, I'm not sure on how authentication works with Scrapy, so I don't know what's the best approach for this website.

The log in URL is: https://www.albertacannabis.org/login

I've tried the following codes:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class AlbertaspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'albertaspider'
    with open("./alberta_parsed_input.txt", "r") as f:
        start_urls = f.readlines()

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@id="_CRSFform"]/input/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata={'__RequestVerificationToken': token,
                                                   'Password': 'foobar',
                                                   'UserName': 'foobar'},
                                        callback=self.scrape_pages)

        product_code = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-title-0"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        print(product_code)
```

And:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider

class AlbertaspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'albertaspider'
    login_url = "https://www.albertacannabis.org/login"
    with open("./alberta_parsed_input.txt", "r") as f:
        start_urls = f.readlines()
    def init_request(self):
        return scrapy.Request(
            url=self.login_url,
            callback=self.login,
        )
    def login(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response=response,
            formid='__RequestVerificationToken',
            formdata={
                'UserName': 'foo@gmail.com',
                'Password': 'bar',
            },
            callback=self.initialized,
        )
    def parse(self, response):
        product_code = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-title-0"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        print(product_code)
```

Both with no avail. I've read a couple of guides online but I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: I think your authentication problem is due to the use of captcha in the log in page.

Comment: Use the information from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968201/446440